# Accessing a control included in a data template

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a ContentControl which is used to display the current item in a CollectionViewSource.

This ContentControl used a DataTemplate to display a RichTextBox. I want to have access to the RichTextBox so I can scroll it to a predetermined location. However I can't seem to access it - how would I obtain a reference to the RichTextBox element?

Many thanks.

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="Results"
                      Source="{Binding Results}">
</CollectionViewSource>


<Grid.Resources>
    <!--Data Templates-->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VFClass:Script}"
                  x:Key="scriptTemplate">
        <RichTextBox x:Name="ScriptViewRichTextBox"
                     local:RichTextBoxHelper.DocumentXaml="{Binding HighlightedRTF, IsAsync=False}"
                     BorderThickness="0"
                     ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                     IsReadOnly="{Binding ReadOnly}"
                     Margin="0"
                     ContextMenuOpening="RichTextBox_ContextMenuOpening"
                     Padding="5">
        </RichTextBox>
    </DataTemplate>
</Grid.Resources>



<ContentControl x:Name="ScriptText"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Margin="0"
                Content="{Binding IsAsync=False, Source={StaticResource Results}}"
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource scriptTemplate}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `VisualTreeHelper`, you can drill down in the visual hierarchy. Assuming you have access to the `ContentControl` itself. (Recursively) use `VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount` and `VisualTreeHelper.GetChild` to access the actual visual tree of the `ContentControl`, until you reach the `RichTextBox` you're interested in:

```
        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(contentControl);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            DependencyObject d = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(contentControl, i);
            if (d is RichTextBox)
            {
                //...do your thing
            }

            //  recurse (if necessary)...
        }
```

Comment: This is ultimately what I went with. Found a more elaborate version here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579(v=vs.110).aspx but to be honest this answer is much simpler!

Answer (score 0):

You can use FindName function of template like you have write in following code in you code behind

```
var template = ControlWhereTemplateAssign.Template;
var myControl = (RichTextBox)template.FindName("ScriptViewRichTextBox", ControlWhereTemplateAssign);
```

Answer (score 0):

this would be much easier if a `ControlTemplate` is applied on the `Control` instead of a `DataTemplate` on the `ContentPresenter`

since the template is being assigned by name so it may not be an issue here.

start by modifying the template

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="scriptTemplate">
    <RichTextBox x:Name="ScriptViewRichTextBox"
                 ... >
    </RichTextBox>
</ControlTemplate>
```

specify as

```
<ContentControl x:Name="ScriptText"
                ...
                Template="{StaticResource scriptTemplate}">
```

access the control as

```
    if (ScriptText.ApplyTemplate())
    {
        RichTextBox rtb = (RichTextBox)ScriptText.Template.FindName("ScriptViewRichTextBox", ScriptText);
    }
```

or (if template already applied)

```
    RichTextBox rtb = (RichTextBox)ScriptText.Template.FindName("ScriptViewRichTextBox", ScriptText);
```

however `FindName` applies to `DataTemplate` as well but there are few conditions which govern the template so you may encounter exceptions using this method

eg

> This operation is valid only on elements that have this template applied.

using ControlTemplate you have option to apply template manually by calling ApplyTemplate() method, hence more safe to retrieve the template objects.

Comment: I need the content of the RichTextBox control to change according to the selected item in the CollectionViewSource. The problem with changing to a ControlTemplate, it seems, is that I need to manually raise an event when the item changes. Also it seems to change the datacontext to the window's view model, rather than to the selected item directly - not such a huge issue, but it seems rather awkward. Thoughts?

Comment: you may set the `DataContext` of `RichTextBox` as `DataContext="{Binding IsAsync=False, Source={StaticResource Results}}"` and there should not be any difference in the expected behavior. and you may not need to fire any event to update the same.